# Android dropshadow on bitmap with rounded corners

Tags: java, android, bitmap

so I am currently using this code for making circular bitmaps:

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
        bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = 36;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
  }
```

And I want to add a drop shadow to the edges of the circle, how do I do this?

Thanks, Swift

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `Paint` to add shadow using `setShadowLayer` method

Use your current paint object like this

```
paint.setShadowLayer(10f, 0f, 0f, Color.DKGRAY)
```